# How to set 2 prices for a product and add to cart same both 2 prices magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, simple-product, multiple, custom-prices

> Actually am trying to show 2 or more prices for a simple product and
>   once we add to cart and  it should sum the prices to cart and also
>   display same prices in shopping cart.
>
> If anyone have any idea,please guide me.

Comment: As of my knowledge, you can follow these steps
1. To display second price, create an attribute like product price and say it like custom_price and fetch it on pdp or wherever you want to display.
2. Then sum of both the prices and set it in the quote from the observer "checkout_cart_add_after" .
3. Fetch the custom_attribute price in cart as well for the particular product.
Hence the cart total will the sum of two prices and you're eventually displaying both the prices on PDP and cart as well.
Thanks and hope this could help out anyway.

Comment: G Prathap,yes i am also thinking like you only